# Mingle Javascript variable and DIV ID name in jQuery Selectory

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, jquery-selectors

I have a Javascript Variable as follows, which get it's DiV ID value.

```
var aishu=$(this).closest('div').parent().closest('div').attr('id');
```

Let's say, the value of variable aishu is std_1

Now I need to have a jQuery selector in the following form

```
$('#' + aishu #size).hide();
```

Which selects the DIV that is contained in the JS variable and select the dropdown with the ID 'size' inside it.

Comment: `$('#'+aishu+' #size').hide();`

Answer (score 1):

You need to concatenate static selector as string:

```
$('#' + aishu +' #size').hide();
```

How ever IDs are always unique. You can simply use id selector for element with id=size:

```
$('#size').hide();
```